# Multiple #ids with a lot of the same code in each, but with slight differences -- efficient way to write this?

Tags: css

Hey all this might sound like a completely noob question, but I've never really learned how to do this. I have a bunch of IDs like this:

```
#f1 {
    a lot of styles!

    order: 1;
}

#f2 {
    a lot of styles!

    order: 2;
}
```

I mean I'm copy/pasting like 40 times. Is there a way to consolidate the "a lot of styles!" into one thing that repeats for all of them, but just write the differing orders for each of the individual ids?

Thanks for any help! :-)

Comment: Consider using a class. This is what its meant for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a common selector for your 'a lot of styles!':

```
#f1, #f2 {
    a lot of styles!
}

#f1 { order: 1; }    
#f2 { order: 2; }
```

A proper alternative, to reduce the first selector, is to assign a class to each element, for example .common and replacing `#f1, #f2, ...` by `.common`

More information : [CSS element,element Selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_comma.asp)

Comment: Hey, awesome! Thanks :-) Will give you answer as soon as I can.

Answer (score 3):

Use a `class` and `id`s

EXAMPLE

CSS

```
.className {
    // common style that they all share
}

#f1 {
    // distinct styles only this id will use
}
#f2 {
    // distinct styles only this id will use
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="className" id="f1">
</div>

<div class="className" id="f2">
</div>
```